# My hook is not updating as I m getting data from api using redux toolkit in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I m getting data using api in redux toolkit method in react native. I m getting data in console but my hook is not updating on page load

```
import { widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Calendar } from 'react-native-calendars';

import colors from '../Styles/colors';
import MainHeader from '../Components/Header/MainHeader';


import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { calanderAction } from "../Redux/Features/CalanderKit/CalanderKit";
import FlatListItem from '../Components/FlatList/FlatList';    

const Attendance = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const calanderHere = useSelector((state) => state.calander);
    // console is working fine and data is fetching
    // console.log("calanderHereInsider", calanderHere?.posts?.result?.attendance);
    const [calanderData, setCalanderData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(calanderAction("170838"));
        // here hook is not updating
         setCalanderData(calanderHere);
    }, [calanderData])
    }));

return(
<></>

)}
```

Comment: Didn't you mean to add calanderHere as dependency to your useEffect?

Comment: No, its not working

Answer (score 0):

You have created an infinite loop. The component mounts and the useEffect is run. setCalendarData will asynchronously update the data value and trigger a rerender. During the re-render the useEffect will be run again.

```
useEffect(() => {
     setCalanderData(calanderHere); // setting state here
}, [calanderData]) // re-rendering whenever calanderData state changes
```

The dependency array tells React what to 'watch' for to trigger re-renders. So as is, it will re-render whenever the calendarData changes, but you are setting it in the useEffect, so the calendarData changes, so the useEffect re-renders, so the calendarData is set. You can see how this creates an infinite loop.

Change the useEffect hook to something like this:

```
const [calanderData, setCalanderData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(calanderAction("170838"));
    setCalanderData(calanderHere);
}, []) // an empty array will only run on component mount
console.log(calendarData); // what does the console show here?
```